# CSS, Enable style on condition

Tags: css

I am working on my website so it look and work almost the same even if JavaScript is disabled, So i have a INPUT and TEXTAREA tags when JavaScript is enabled i can focus my mouse on the INPUT and the TEXTAREA style become `display: block` from `display: none`, Is there a way to check with CSS if the user is focus on the INPUT tag and then apply some styles to the TEXTAREA tag?, Thank you all and have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `adjacent selector` like this:

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jxJZ3/)**

**HTML:**

```
Click on the text input
<input type="text">
<textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

**CSS**

```
input[type=text]:focus {border:1px solid red; }
textarea { display:none; }
input[type=text]:focus + textarea {display:block; }
```

Though you will notice that you can't actually click and focus on the textarea when it appears.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the `textarea` after the `textbox` than yes, you can use `+` `adjacent selector`

```
textarea {
    display: none;
}

input[type=text]:focus + textarea { 
/* Switching styles for textarea when textbox is focused*/
    display: block;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/26MQu/)

> Note: Add a class to `input[type=text]` for selecting specific
>   element, else the above selector will trigger all `textarea` and
>   `input[type=text]` elements

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it with CSS using [Pseudo-classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/Pseudo-classes) 
Example for [:focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3afocus)

Answer (score 1):

To avoid hiding the `textarea` after focusing on `input` use the following:

```
textarea:hover,textarea:focus{
    display:block;
}
```

See the [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/MVE7p/).